# Stormpath for JWT authentication/authorization with Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, jwt, stormpath

We are looking into authentication/authorization for a mobile reporting app which consumes hourly/weekly/monthly commercially sensitive data over the wire using an internally provided RESTful web api service running within the MS Azure Cloud.
Stormpath's offering looks interesting in that it would appear to provide some heavy lift for the whole identity management side of things, registering users, authenticating them and producing JWT tokens etc.
Otherwise, we would have to write our own auth/user db tables and have some management overhead with that.

What I am not fully clear on is where our current unsecure, unauthenticated prototype API served up by Azure would need to intersect with Stormpath.
Can anyone, especially those familiar with Stormath elaborate on this?

I get that all the user registration, password recovery use cases would go via Stormpath and I am guessing that JWT token creation for a user would require our existing service to talk to Stormpath. Would the validation of tokens within the HTTP(S) headers of our RESTful calls be done by our Azure service locally (via some code plugin) and if so is that validation done locally or does each RESTful call have a side effect of proxying calls to Stormpath API to validate the goodness of a token?

I guess I am sensitive to performance issues regarding the whole token validation step within the Web API pipeline.

I've read elsewhere that Microsoft themselves have an offering, namely Azure AD B2C which it seems is not production ready for regions outside of US/North America as of yet.
Is that something else we should consider as an alternative to an outsourced offering like Stormpath?

One thing which looks attractive about something like Stormpath is the possibility of two factor authentication.
Without having gone into too much analysis yet, a typical use case scenario would be that sign up or password recovery would mandate that an SMS was sent to the user's preregistered smartphone number to provide a stronger validation that they (and their pre-registered device) are the intended user of the mobile app which uses the RESTful service to consume and visualise commercially sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work at Stormpath on our .NET libraries.

> What I am not fully clear on is where our current unsecure, unauthenticated prototype API served up by Azure would need to intersect with Stormpath.

Stormpath acts as your API's source of access tokens. When someone using your mobile app needs to log in, your backend API uses Stormpath to generate an access token, or the mobile app talks directly to Stormpath to get an access token. Either way, the token allows the mobile app to make **authenticated** requests to your API.

> Would the validation of tokens within the HTTP(S) headers of our RESTful calls be done by our Azure service locally (via some code plugin) and if so is that validation done locally or does each RESTful call have a side effect of proxying calls to Stormpath API to validate the goodness of a token?

The access token (JWT) integrity can be validated locally using middleware like `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` in ASP.NET. For more security, you can send the token up to Stormpath to be verified even further (for revocation and other cases), but the tradeoff is a network request. Local (fast) validation is the default, but we give you both options.

> I've read elsewhere that Microsoft themselves have an offering, namely Azure AD B2C which it seems is not production ready for regions outside of US/North America as of yet. Is that something else we should consider as an alternative to an outsourced offering like Stormpath?

Using either Stormpath or Azure AD B2C is "outsourcing" your identity and user management. The benefit is that you don't have to write it yourself, and you can focus on writing your business and app logic instead. The features are similar, although Stormpath is a little more flexible on the mobile side of things (since you aren't forced to use a browser/page-based flow).